# Why don't languages include implication as a logical operator?

Tags: language-design

It might be a strange question, but why there is no implication as a logical operator in many languages (Java, C, C++, Python Haskell - although as last one have user defined operators its trivial to add it)? I find logical implication much clearer to write (particularly in asserts or assert-like expressions) then negation with or:

```
encrypt(buf, key, mode, iv = null) {
    assert (mode != ECB --> iv != null);
    assert (mode == ECB || iv != null);
    assert (implies(mode != ECB, iv != null)); // User-defined function
}
```

Comment: Because it wasn't put in C; if it have been put then C++, Java and C# would have had it.

Comment: But C doesn't have it, in turn, because it's not a common part of assembly language. Whereas as all instruction sets I know of include and, or and not, I know of none that include implies - no doubt someone will be along to tell me of some obscure instruction set that does shortly...

Comment: @JackAidley: Not exactly implies but Intel's MMX have and not which is inverse of the implies. If ISA in general constitute something obscure nowadays is of course matter of debate.

Comment: Maybe it was considered redundant because (1) it is less primitive than "^", "v", "~", (2) it saves very little typing since "A => B" is equivalent to "~A v B".

Comment: Languages that deal with logical constructions are more likely to have it.  Chiefly among these is [prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775651/whats-the-operator-in-prolog-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: BTW `Imp` and `Eqv` were in VB6, but did not survive the .NET transition.

Comment: b.t.w Cobra has an `implies` operator which fits its design-by-contract philosophy. (Though your example isn't good, since you don't want implication, you want equivalence, since ECB can't take an IV)

Comment: back in the day, Tandy BASIC had `IMP`

Comment: I'm surprised that you think `assert` #1 is clearer than #2. I have stared at #1 for some time and still can't see how it's behaviour could be considered intuitive. (especially with the extra `!=` flipping the logic)

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown: Possibly it's result of too much logic and type systems but I'm surprised second may be clearer - first one clearly says "whenever mode is not ECB iv must not be null" while second states "either mode is ECB or iv is not null". They are logically equivalent but first one IMHO conveys the intent better (although I admit that it looks like the believe is not exactly widely shared).

Comment: Seems implication is possible in Haskell : "Logical implication is a common enough operator, usually written "a => b" for a implies b. Haskell doesn't feature a => operator, it would be a syntax error because that symbol is reserved for class constraints. Both QuickCheck and SmallCheck feature incompatible ==> operators for implication. But Haskell does provide a boolean implication operator, namely (<=)! Yes, by writing the implication symbol backwards, you get standard forward implication!" Taken from http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2007/02/logical-implication-in-haskell.html

Comment: *troll* Because --> is already taken by the "goes to operator" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Comment: I guess whether the implies operator is intuitive or not is 90% training and habit. To me the first assert is by far better. Nobody would use such an operator because nobody is trained to.

Comment: As I recall PL/I had both IMP and EQV. Also Coldfusion and many dialects of Basic. In some languages x<=Y and x==y for booleans serve the same purpose. Not rare at all.

Comment: You might be interested by [expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) and their [inference engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference_engine). You should have a look into [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) and [proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) like [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/)

Comment: @Giorgio: Were I designing a language, I would make "andnot" a primitive. Just as one doesn't typically arithmetically subtract Y from X by writing X+= -Y, nor should one bitwise-subtract Y from X by writing "X &= ~Y".  Not all forms of logic can synthesize a "not" operator or a "true" value, but even many that can't could still support "and not". For example, given two sets of strings X=["Moe", "Larry", "Curly"] and Y=["Homer", "Moe", "Lenny"], computing the set "X andnot Y" should not require producing the set of all strings which are not present in Y.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It could be useful to have sometimes, no doubt. Several points argue against such an operator:

- The characters `-` and `>` are valuable, both in isolation and combined. Many languages already use them to mean other things. (And many can't use unicode character sets for their syntax.)
- Implication is very counter-intuitive, even to logic-minded people such as programmers. The fact that three out of the four truth table entries are `true` surprises many people.
- All other logical operators are symmetrical, which would make `->` an exception to orthogonality.
- At the same time, there is an easy workaround: use operators `!` and `||`.
- Implication is used vastly less often than logical `and`/`or`.

This is probably why the operator is rare today. Certainly it could become more common, as new dynamic languages use Unicode for everything and operator overloading becomes more fashionable again.

Comment: Your first point only argues against using '-->' as the symbol for the operator, not against actually having the operator.  The others are good points.

Comment: "At the same time, there is an easy workaround: use ! and &&.": In fact, the simplest way of simulating "->" (or "=>", as it is more common in Math), is to use `!` and `||`, not `!` and `&&`: `A -> B` is equivalent to `!A || B` which is equivalent to `!(A && !B)`.

Comment: "The fact that three out of the four truth table entries are true surprises many people." Wat. I know another operator with the same feature which is used rather often...

Comment: @l0b0 Yeah, but for or, that's what everyone expects. The same doesn't apply to implication.

Comment: @svick: These blanket statements about other developers is a bit strange. I'd expect people who have studied CS to think something like "anything can follow from a false premise, while a true premise can only lead to a true result."

Comment: @l0b0 Not every developer has studied computer science. And I think understanding a simple condition shouldn't require a CS degree.

Comment: @l0b0, I'm a programmer who studied CS, but it was a long time ago. I had forgotten that "implies" is a formal operation with two operands that returns a truth value, so at first I was confused at the nature of this question. In everyday speech, I only ever use "implies" when the first operand is already known to be true ("X is true, so Y must be true"). After a minute, I remembered how formal "implies" works, but the fact remains -- even for someone who once did study formal logic, the intent was not clear to me. And if I had never studied it, it wouldn't have even eventually made sense.

Comment: (a) In C -> is used as an operator. No one complains about that. I would use => anyway. (b) Counter-intuitive to whom? The definition of implication is just that, a definition. (c) subtraction is not commutative. No one complains about that. (d) I think you mean ! and ||. Because of precedence ( and ) are often also needed. The same argument could be used against && or ||; take your pick. (e) Perhaps that is because it is not in most languages. Many uses of || could be concisely and (to me at least) intuitively replaced by implication.

Comment: After rereading @TheodoreNorvell reply - I'd start to think how many people would find surprising that or is inclusive in programming if the usage having been long established.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Subtraction (and division) are not logical operators.  They are mathematical operators.

Comment: @Izkata I was making an analogy between logical operations and arithmetic operations. Also, on this point, the objection is that the lack of symmetry somehow makes implication "an exception to orthogonality". I don't see what symmetry and orthogonality have to do with each other. Not begin symmetric makes implication an exception among the set of binary logical operations commonly offered in programming languages; but what could be an "exception to orthogonality"? Of course being exceptional is hardly an objection, especially if, like implication, the construct is exceptionally useful.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell It's probably a reference to the "simplicity" part of the meaning [used here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science), since it would be the only non-symmetrical logical operator

Comment: <snarky>These arguments all sound like coming from someone who desperately wants to justify not brushing his teeth.</snarky> But then again, even Erlang doesn't have it and in Prolog it basically indicates the search tree branch.

Comment: my guess is because it's not commutative (a -> b) != (b -> a) whereas other popular boolean operators are in fact commutative. Commutative operators you can rearrange freely without worry or concern. I would like to think that implication would be useful, but I guess it's often easier to spell out the !a || b since there isn't any room for confusion.

Answer (score 55):

I believe the answer lies in [the mathematical foundations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). Implication is usually considered and defined as a derived, not elementary, operation of boolean algebras. Programming languages follow this convention.

This is Proposition I of Chapter II from George Boole's [An Investigation of the Laws of Thought (1854)](http://gutenberg.org/ebooks/15114):

> All the operations of Language, as an instrument of reasoning, may be conducted by a system of signs composed of the following elements, viz.:
>
> 1st. Literal symbols, as x, y, &c., representing things as subjects of our conceptions.
>
> 2nd. Signs of operation, as +, −, ×, standing for those operations of the mind by which the conceptions of things are combined or resolved so as to form new conceptions involving the same elements.
>
> 3rd. The sign of identity, =.
>
> And these symbols of Logic are in their use subject to definite laws, partly agreeing with and partly differing from the laws of the corresponding symbols in the science of Algebra.

Boole's sign + represents the same "operation of the mind" we today recognize as both the boolean ´or´ and the union of sets. Similarly the signs − and × correspond to our boolean negation, complement of a set, boolean ´and´ and intersection of sets.

Comment: +1 - solid answer.  Boolean algebra and the simplifications in logic that it allows drives a lot of programming methodology.  Using an "implies ..." would potentially interfere with "don't care" conditions.

Comment: 1. That depend on definition. It is possible to define or as `a || b = !(!a && !b)` (I met or as derived operator in logic). 2. The reason why it is done is usually to simplify induction proves I believe (we know that derived operators are just short-cuts so we don't need to have separate case for them). @GlenH7: What "don't care" conditions? `a --> b` is the same as `!a || b`.

Comment: Also - we have other derived operators like xor (`!=`) nxor (`==`)...

Comment: Actually, you can derive everything from either NAND `!(a && b)` or NOR `!(a || b)`. For example, `NOT a == a NAND a`, `a AND b == NOT(a NAND b)`, `a OR b == (NOT a) NAND (NOT b)`. But providing only a NAND operator puts you in the realm of esoteric languages (which fits surprisingly well, given the answerer's username ;-) ).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: True, this depends on definition. Just about everything in mathematics depends on definitions. And sure, (!=) and (==) could be interpreted as xor and xnor (though I wouldn't consider them boolean operators at all). What I wanted to point out is that there are conventions about definitions and specifically about definitions of Boolean algebras. Furthermore, there are reasons and history behind these conventions, and that history goes way beyond the scope of modern programming languages.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Due to short-circuiting, `a || b` and `!(!a && !b)` are not equivalent.  The first will evaluate `b` in situations where the second will not, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Izkata: It depends on language. In C/C++/Java/... you're right but there are languages which does not have it specified (Haskell for example IIRC).

Comment: @Izkata: First one will evaluate `b` iff `a` is `false` and second will evaluate `b` iff `!a` is `true`. In other words second will evaluate `b` iff `a` is `false`. So they should be equivalent unless I missed something.

Comment: @Stefan: You can also derive everything from an IMPL.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that think about this as a compression scheme. What operators are widely used? then support them as atomic operation which means you don't have to have long encoding to express it. Sometimes even composite operators like XOR are compressed into a seemingly elementary operator because people use it a lot.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky: Some contexts support primitives `X or Y` and `X andnot Y`, but cannot support `nand` nor `nor`. For example, if X and Y were sets of names, one could produce a list of names that appear in exactly one list, or that appear only in the first, but one cannot produce a list of names that don't appear in either.  Note that the aformentioned primitives are sufficient to derive `X and Y` and `X xor Y`.  Although one could derive `X andnot Y` from `X and Y` and `X xor Y` [`(X xor Y) and X`], I think `andnot` is more commonly useful.

Comment: After a thought - programming probably have a lot more in common constructive logic then classical one (the operation symbols and derive rules including Hoare Logic, Curry–Howard correspondence etc.). In the former the negation (and everything else) is defined in terms of implication rather then other way round.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka - fyi, Haskell does have clearly defined order of evaluation for the arguments to boolean operations. It may seem counter-intuitive for a pure language, but it is important in the case that either one argument throws an exception or is infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 40):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in November 2015](http://ericlippert.com/2015/11/05/logical-implication/). Thanks for the interesting question!

---

Visual Basic 6 (and VBScript) had `Imp` and `Eqv` operators. No one used them. Both were removed in VB.NET; to my knowledge, no one complained.

I worked on the Visual Basic compiler team (as an intern) for a full year and never once noticed that VB even had those operators. Had I not been the guy writing the VBScript compiler, and therefore had to test their implementations, I probably would not have noticed them. If the guy on the *compiler team* doesn't know about the feature and doesn't use it, that tells you something about the popularity and usefulness of the feature.

You mentioned C-like languages. I can't speak to C or C++ or Java but I can speak to C#. There is a list of user-suggested features for C# literally longer than your arm. To my knowledge, no user has ever proposed such an operator to the C# team, and I've gone over that list many, many times.

Features that exist and are unused in one language, and are never requested in another are unlikely candidates to make it into modern programming languages. Particularly when there is not enough time and effort and money available in the budget to make features that people *do* want.

Comment: IMP goes back as an operator to GWBASIC days. I remember it from 1979.

Comment: I've read that IMPL is very helpful for code contracts.  (Which VB didn't have.)

Comment: VBScript programmers were probably the group least likely to use such an operator. I'm wishing right now that PowerShell had an implies operator so I could more easily & legibly implement some `[switch]` filter parameters.

Comment: I remember IMP from DEC BASIC.  I don't remember `EQV`.  The operator I've often wished for would be "and not", which would promote the right-hand operator *before* negating it.  Thus, `0xABCD12345678ul ~& 0x00200000u` would yield 0xABCD12145678ul rather than 0x12145678ul.

Answer (score 21):

I can only guess, but a reason might be that there are workarounds which are quite simple and readable. Let's consider your example:

```
if (mode != ECB) assert (iv != null);

assert (mode != ECB --> iv != null);  // <-- that's only one character shorter
```

If you need an expression, the inline-if operator available in most languages (often called the ternary operator) can be used. Granted, this is not as elegant as `A --> B`, but the number of use cases might not justify adding (and maintaining!) another operator:

```
assert (mode != ECB ? iv != null : true);
```

Comment: As of asserts - there is good reason. First one will produce (in many implementations) message "assertion failure: iv != null" while second "assertion failure: mode != ECB --> iv != null".

Comment: +1, I was about to ask this same thing on the question (since I'm not very familiar with "implication", it never comes up day-to-day).  The `if` statement is far, far clearer to just about everyone.

Answer (score 17):

Eiffel has Implication

It actually has even more. It has a number of semi-strict operators as well as strict.

The reason programmers do not use such things is because they are never trained to know precisely what they are, how to use them, and when to use them -- as well as how to design with them. Because they are never trained, they never ask for it from the compiler writers, which is why the compiler people do not bother putting such mechanisms in the compiler. When Computer Science students and Shade-tree programmers begin getting a more rounded education, then the compilers will start catching up.

It turns out that once you have a language with such Boolean operators and you know how to design with them and use them, then you use them.

In Eiffel the use of the "implies" keyword is rather prominent because of Design-by-Contract due to the Boolean-heavy nature of contract assertions. There are some contracts that can only be written properly and efficiently with the "implies" operator. This then begs the comment that languages without contracts are further without cause to look at, train, and implement the use of implication.

Add to this that most programmers are "math-and-logic-weak" tells us the remainder of the story. Even if you are math-and-logic-heavy in your education, when one chooses a language that does not implement constructs such as implication, then one tends to think such things are unnecessary or not useful. One rarely questions the language and gets into an echo-chamber of: "Well the compiler guys don't see the need" and "Well the programmers don't see the need" -- endless and vicious circle.

Instead, the compiler people need to back up to the theory, write a language notation that is suggested or implied by the theory (e.g. Object Oriented Theory) regardless of what the unwashed masses of programmers think or ask for. From there, professors, teachers, and other professionals need to expertly train young mush-minds based on raw theory and NOT "theory-through-the-language-lens". When this happens, people will suddenly wake up and realize what they have been missing and what has been foisted on them.

Right now -- there is so much theory out there that masquerades as Object Oriented, but is just O-O-through-a-glass-darkly-of-[pick-your-language]. One cannot read most "theory" books on O-O because they want to interpret what the theory is through the lens of some language. Totally false and incorrect. It would be like teaching math-based-on-my-calculator or my slide rule. NO -- one allows reality to teach one about itself and then uses a notation to describe what one observes -- that's called "science". This other mash called O-O-based-on-language-X is so skewed as to barely represent reality.

So, step away from the language, take a look at raw theory, and begin again. Do not let limitations, constraints, and paint-jobs of a language tell you what the theory is. Simply let the reality of the theory dictate its own notation and then move from there into formulating a language.

From there, you will start to get how implication and "implies" is not only useful, but elegant and very cool!

Have a great one!

Answer (score 8):

Python has an implication operator in a sort of hidden way.

The less-than-or-equals operator is overloaded to accept boolean values. As a result, one can use it as an implication operator.

Proof by Example (Python Code):

```
print (False <= False) # This will print True.
print (False <= True)  # This will print True.
print (True <= False)  # This will print False.
print (True <= True)   # This will print True.
```

Recall the truth table of the implication operator is:

```
LEFT RIGHT RESULT
F    F     T
F    T     T
T    F     F
T    T     T
```

Comment: This is awesome, but unfortunately has the wrong strictness properties: `f() implies g()` should not evaluate `g()` if `f()` is `False`, but `<=` does evaluate `g()` in this case.

Comment: @Jon Purdy - Strictly speaking, short-circuit evaluation is an optional feature of binary operators. So technically, this is a perfectly legitimate implementation of the implication-operator. That being said, I really doubt that Guido van Rossum even intended this to be an implication-operator. This is just a quirk of comparing booleans.

Comment: Sure, I was saying it’s an interesting observation, but not something you should use in real programs because it isn’t short-circuiting and that could take somebody by surprise if they expected `did_all_possible_stuff = x.do_required_stuff() and (x.supports_optional_stuff() <= x.do_optional_stuff())` to work.

Comment: This works in C and C++ as well.

Answer (score 5):

Eiffel has an "implies" operator and it is very nice for writting pre- and postconditions.
It makes code more readable, unfortunately that was never a fundamental intension for C like language and too few people used eiffel so the beauty of "implies" as operator is not well known.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the big problem with implies comes when the initial condition is false; for example: "If the sun is green, then I am a fruit bat." True!

In formal logic it just works to assign "True" to the value when the condition of the implication isn't met. But in programming, that could lead to counter-intuitive and surprising results.

I actually think the example @Heinzi gives above:

```
if (sun.color() == "green") then assert(me.species() == "fruitbat")
```

Is much easier to understand, and less prone to errors due to misunderstanding the logic.

In the context of testing, I'd just halt the moment my assumptions became false:

```
assert(sun.color() == "green")
assert(me.species() == "fruitbat")
```

So, to @Eric Lippert's point, as a programmer I don't know when I'd use an implies operator. The "False is True" behavior seems useful in the context of mathematical, formal logic, but could lead to unexpected results in program logic.

...

No one has mentioned the common "?" operator, where "A ? B : true" is the same as "implies". But while formal logic assigns true to the "else" condition, "?" lets the developer assign that explicitly.

In formal logic, using "true" works out, but in programming, if the condition is false, then the better answer is more like "null" or "void" or "skip", or even maybe false.

I think someone would have to make the case why "implies" is a more useful operator than "?", or "if" statements, or just regular program flow.

Answer (score 1):

[Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/) has [`implies`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=implies#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/bool..rkt%29._implies%29%29). It macro-expands to an `if` expression.